# is cmake 3.0.2 on Debian 8.11 gone crazy? (updated)

Tags: gcc, cmake, debian

update:
no matter on cmake version (tried 3.0.2 and 3.15.4) nor gcc, 
the problem is present when the project is on a shared folder on host machine
(host is Debian 9 and guest is Debian 8), problem arised updating one of: VirtualBox 6.0.12 or guestAdditions 0.20.0 or vagrant 2.2.5 and maybe is related to changed time-execution or different privileges in mounting)

---

the problem happens both with an old and a just created Debian 8 VMs
the old VM worked well for months and suddenly had this problem, creating a brand new VM gives the same.
CMake is no longer able to find c/c++ compilers even if gcc 4.9.2 is up and running
and a.out files are created from sample c/c++ programs.

- OS Debian jessie 8.11 (VirtualBox 6.0.12 created with vagrant 2.2.5)
- cmake version 3.0.2
- gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u2) 4.9.2

my helloworld.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

my CMakeLists.txt:

```
project (hello)
add_executable(hello helloworld.cpp)
```

Running cmake

```
$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:172 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:170 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)

-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:47 (try_compile):
  Unknown extension ".c" for file

    <my-project-dir>/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  try_compile() works only for enabled languages.  Currently these are:

    C CXX

  See project() command to enable other languages.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:


  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "<my-project-dir>/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "<my-project-dir>/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: It could be unrelated, but using `cmake_minimum_required` before the `project()` call is a good tone and may prevent many weird problems.

Comment: exactly the same result adding 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
as 1st line